# Magento 2 + Nginx: Multiple websites homepages work but every other URL is 404

Tags: magento2, nginx, multisite

I've searched high and low for a solution to this problem but none of the solutions to any of the existing questions has helped.

I have a freshly installed ( via Composer ) Magento 2 site. I am using Nginx and PHP-FPM.

I would like to have multiple websites running under one Magento 2 installation. I have created two websites in Magento admin with the codes "us_website", and "uk_website". I would like to have each of these sites running under a sub-directory with the following format:

http://somedomain.com/us/store/

http://somedomain.com/uk/store/

I have changed the base urls in the website configuration area and have created folders with index.php files for these sites as follow:

/pub/us/store/index.php

/pub/uk/store/index.php

And it seems that the homepages for these two websites are using these index.php files; if I make a change to either of these two website specific index.php files I can see these changes when I visit their respective homepages.

If I try to visit any other url other than the homepage urls ( for example: /us/store/contact/ ) I get a 404. It seems like any request to a url that is not the homepage url is using /pub/index.php because when I make changes to the website specific index.php files I do not see those changes, but if I change /pub/index.php I can see those changes.

My default.conf:

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {

    server unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;

}

map $request_uri $country {

    ~^/(?<suffix>.*)/store/ $suffix;

}


server {

    listen *:80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    client_max_body_size 50M;

    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento;

    set $MAGE_RUN_TYPE website;

    set $MAGE_MODE developer;

    set $MAGE_RUN_CODE "${country}_website";
    set $MAGE_RUN_TYPE website;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;

    include conf/global/magento.conf;

}
```

My magento.conf:

```
root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

index index.php;
autoindex off;
charset UTF-8;
error_page 404 403 = /errors/404.php;
#add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge";

# PHP entry point for setup application
location ~* ^/setup($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;
    location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

# PHP entry point for update application
location ~* ^/update($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;

    location ~ ^/update/index.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Deny everything but index.php
    location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}


location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location /pub/ {
    location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
        deny all;
    }
    alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub/;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /static/ {
    # Uncomment the following line in production mode
    # expires max;

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    location ~ ^/static/version {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;

    location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/customer/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/downloadable/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/import/ {
    deny all;
}

# PHP entry point for main application
location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;

    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE $MAGE_RUN_TYPE;
    fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE $MAGE_RUN_CODE;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types
text/plain
text/css
text/js
text/xml
text/javascript
application/javascript
application/x-javascript
application/json
application/xml
application/xml+rss
image/svg+xml;
gzip_vary on;

# Banned locations (only reached if the earlier PHP entry point regexes don't match)
location ~* (\.php$|\.htaccess$|\.git) {
    deny all;
}
```

My /pub/index.php looks like:

```
<?php
/**
 * Public alias for the application entry point
 *
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

try {
    require realpath(__DIR__) . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}

$params = $_SERVER;
$params[Bootstrap::INIT_PARAM_FILESYSTEM_DIR_PATHS] = [
    DirectoryList::PUB => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => ''],
    DirectoryList::MEDIA => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'media'],
    DirectoryList::STATIC_VIEW => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'static'],
    DirectoryList::UPLOAD => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'media/upload'],
];

$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = $_SERVER[ 'MAGE_RUN_CODE' ];
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = $_SERVER[ 'MAGE_RUN_TYPE' ];

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('\Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

My website specific index.php files look like:

```
<?php
/**
 * Application entry point
 *
 * Example - run a particular store or website:
 * --------------------------------------------
 * require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
 * $params = $_SERVER;
 * $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'uk_website';
 * $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
 * $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
 * \/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app *\/
 * $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
 * $bootstrap->run($app);
 * --------------------------------------------
 *
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */


try {
    require __DIR__ . '/../../../app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}

$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'us_website';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('\Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

Comment: Maybe, just maybe, its the ~* directive in your nginx.conf, but most likely those just prohibit direct access.

Comment: probably you telling nginx to go to location, which he does not know where to find redirect/rewrite to, you must have proper rewrite with your path in magento.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some intial testing I think I have found a solution to my problem.

I ended up adding this snipped to my magento.conf file:

```
location ~* ^/(?<country>.*)/store/ {
    try_files /$country/store/index.php /index.php $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;

    fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE $MAGE_RUN_TYPE;
    fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE $MAGE_RUN_CODE;

    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

So in total my magento.conf file ended up looking like this:

```
## Example configuration:
# upstream fastcgi_backend {
#    # use tcp connection
#    # server  127.0.0.1:9000;
#    # or socket
#    server   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
# }
# server {
#    listen 80;
#    server_name mage.dev;
#    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento2;
#    include /vagrant/magento2/nginx.conf.sample;
# }
#
## Optional override of deployment mode. We recommend you use the
## command 'bin/magento deploy:mode:set' to switch modes instead.
##
## set $MAGE_MODE default; # or production or developer
##
## If you set MAGE_MODE in server config, you must pass the variable into the
## PHP entry point blocks, which are indicated below. You can pass
## it in using:
##
## fastcgi_param  MAGE_MODE $MAGE_MODE;
##
## In production mode, you should uncomment the 'expires' directive in the /static/ location block

root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

index index.php;
autoindex off;
charset UTF-8;
error_page 404 403 = /errors/404.php;
#add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge";

# PHP entry point for setup application
location ~* ^/setup($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;
    location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

# PHP entry point for update application
location ~* ^/update($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;

    location ~ ^/update/index.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Deny everything but index.php
    location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location /pub/ {
    location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
        deny all;
    }
    alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub/;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /static/ {
    # Uncomment the following line in production mode
    # expires max;

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    location ~ ^/static/version {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;

    location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/customer/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/downloadable/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/import/ {
    deny all;
}

location ~* ^/(?<country>.*)/store/ {
    try_files /$country/store/index.php /index.php $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;

    fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE $MAGE_RUN_TYPE;
    fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE $MAGE_RUN_CODE;

    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

# PHP entry point for main application
location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;

    fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE $MAGE_RUN_TYPE;
    fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE $MAGE_RUN_CODE;

    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types
text/plain
text/css
text/js
text/xml
text/javascript
application/javascript
application/x-javascript
application/json
application/xml
application/xml+rss
image/svg+xml;
gzip_vary on;

# Banned locations (only reached if the earlier PHP entry point regexes don't match)
location ~* (\.php$|\.htaccess$|\.git) {
    deny all;
}
```